# No resource identifier found for attribute 'qihoo' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, apktool

I am recompiling miui helper app but on recompiling I am facing an error.

```html
 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.qihoo.util.StubApplication" **android:qihoo="activity"** android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme">
```

Error Log:

> F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\MIUIHelper.apk\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'qihoo' in package 'android'
>
> Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\brut_util_Jar_2355496078147801760.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 15, --target-sdk-version, 22, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, -F, C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\APKTOOL1767990981439973830.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\1-BDFreak\Frameworks\1.apk, -S, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\MIUIHelper.apk\res, -M, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\MIUIHelper.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]
>           at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:459)
>           at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:397)
>           at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:285)
>           at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:256)
>           at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:225)
>           at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
>       Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\brut_util_Jar_2355496078147801760.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 15, --target-sdk-version, 22, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, -F, C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\APKTOOL1767990981439973830.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\1-BDFreak\Frameworks\1.apk, -S, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\MIUIHelper.apk\res, -M, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\MIUIHelper.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]
>           at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:419)
>           at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:445)
>           ... 5 more
>       Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\brut_util_Jar_2355496078147801760.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 15, --target-sdk-version, 22, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, -F, C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\APKTOOL1767990981439973830.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\1-BDFreak\Frameworks\1.apk, -S, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\MIUIHelper.apk\res, -M, F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\MIUIHelper.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]
>           at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:89)
>           at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:413)
>           ... 6 more

Answer (score 0):

Delete **android:qihoo="activity"** from your **manifest** and then run. Also can you please tell us which  attribute is **android:qihoo**

Answer (score 0):

[`Application`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) element in Android manifest file does not have any attribute named `qihoo` and you cannot add your own attributes to this element.

Thus your given manifest file is invalid and that attributed should be removed.